# Capturing the value of the proper input if one is a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Given the following markup:

```
<input name="active" type="hidden" value="0" />
<input id="active" name="active" type="checkbox" value="1" />
```

When the checkbox is unchecked and the form is submitted the server will get a value of "0" for the "active" param. When the checkbox is checked and the form is submitted the server will get a value of "1" for the "active" param. This works just fine.

What I want to do is capture the proper value in JavaScript based upon that. The trick, however, is I don't know if the input is a checkbox or not. As far as my script is concerned it is just acting on a set of inputs.

I have created a JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bcardarella/5QRjF/ that demonstrates the issue.

TL;DR I want to ensure the value I capture from each input is the actual value sent to the server.

Comment: actually the form sends both values in the request if you check the checkbox, maybe what you want to do is to replicate the same logic your server-side language/framework is using to out this as a single value instead of interpret it as an array of values? (check the request in Firebug/Inspector, you get both `active=0` and `active=1` on the request). Pretty sure this is being auto-mapped to a model where active is a number/boolean/string so it first gets set to 0 and then to 1. Both values are used, just one kept.

Answer (score 2):

Don't know if you actually want to check for the checkbox or not, but this code works:

```
$(function() {
    var getCheckBoxValue = function() {
        if ($('[name="active"]:checkbox').attr("checked")) {
            return $('[name="active"]:checkbox').val();
        } else {
            return $('[name="active"]').val();
            }
    }
    var result = $('#result');

    result.append($('<p/>', {text: 'Expected value 0, got: ' + getCheckBoxValue()}));

    $(':checkbox')[0].checked = true;

    result.append($('<p/>', {text: 'Expected value 1, got: ' + getCheckBoxValue()}));
});
```

Basically if the checkbox is checked, use that, otherwise, go with the default value from the hidden input.

**Edit**

Turned my comment into a fiddle, I've also added another field, a text field, to show better the idea behind it: http://jsfiddle.net/45qup/

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ideally I would prefer not to check if any of the inputs are checkboxes. But I suspect I might have to do something similar to what you have here.

Comment: Mh, the only way I can think of, to not check for the checkbox, would be to define some sort of custom event that determines when an input is the "active" one, and set a custom property to that input. After that it would be a matter of checking for that input's value.... hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Write up the click event for the checkbox..

```
$('#active').on('click', function(){

     var isChecked = this.checked;
     var val = 0;
     if(isChecked){
         val = 1
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like

```
$("form#formID :input").each(function(){
   if ($(this).attr() == 'checkbox') return $(this).checked();
   else return $(this).val();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if if I’d go with this ;) , but it works:

```
var getCheckBoxValue = function() {
    var values = $('[name="active"]')
        .filter(':checked, :hidden')
        .map(function(){ 
            return parseInt($(this).val(), 10); 
        }
    );

    return Math.max.apply(Math, values);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Xc5H7/1/

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @Deleteman's idea, this is a slightly simpler way of doing it:

```
var getCheckBoxValue = function() {
    var input = $('[name="active"]');
    return $(input[1].checked ? input[1] : input[0]).val();
}
```

This assumes there's only two fields with this name, which is a sane assumption for what you're trying to do.

It also assumes the hidden field always comes before the checkbox, which again, since this is, I assume, for Rails, is a sane assumption :)